# How to identify the source of a context object in android java?

Tags: java, android, android-context

**Overview**

I am working on android application in java. I have Products which can be viewed as a list by customers and vendors.

**Problem**

I want to be able to utilize the context object that is passed to the **AdapterClass** class as an argument when the adapter is initialized to identify if the adapter is being used to view products by a customer-specific activity or a vendor-specific activity.

This would eliminate the need for two separate adapter classes for displaying products to customers and vendors and also for implementing separate functionalities for both.

For this purpose, inside the adapter, I need to identify the origin of the received context.

**How do I do this?**

```
public class AdapterClass extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterClass.MyViewHolder> {

Context context;
List<String> productList;

public AdapterClass(Context context, List<String> productList){
    this.context=context;
    this.productList = productList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //these if-else conditions are dummy code
    if(context is from ActivityVendor){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.vendor_list_item_layout, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }
    else if(context is from ActivityCustomer){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.customer_list_item_layout, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(context is from ActivityVendor){
        //code for vendor
    }
    else if(context is from ActivityCustomer){
        //code for customer
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.productList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        if(context is from ActivityVendor){
            imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
        else if(context is from ActivityCustomer){
            imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.image2);
            textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: context is AppCompatActivity or in java context instaceOf AppCompatActivity

Comment: This is something you almost certainly should not do.  Especially since you may not be given the context you expect (it's not uncommon to be given a ContextWrapper, which is a context that wraps another context).  What are you trying to do differently, there are probably better ways to do it.

Comment: @GabeSechan yes there are other ways to do it but I hoped to be able to to utilize the context object more and not have to send any more arguments

Comment: Like I said-  explain what you're *actually* trying to do-  the different behavior you wish to enable-  and maybe we can help.  But this is absolutely not something you should be doing.

Comment: @GabeSechan I have updated the description. Please take a look

Answer (score 1):

To determine what code shall do, based up the context it runs within commonly is sub-optimal (it's not that one couldn't do it - but within one single `Activity`, this is pointless). Most commonly one might want to data-bind eg. a `groupId` and then display either view-type ID of a `CardView` layout, depending on the current user group. Meanwhile with MAD, it is rather the situation, that as soon a user has a different role/group, one can simply provide them with their own navigation graph ...